# Как найти несколько корней, когда есть 2 и 3 уравнения?

Tags: python, sympy

У меня есть 2 и 3 уравнения которые может иметь несколько уравнений.
Как найти несколько корней?

Я понимаю, что можно это сделать с помощью sympy. Но не понимаю как.

Например: У меня есть несколько формул:

```
5+x^2=y
y^2+x=3
```

Как можно найти все корни этого уравнения?

Comment: А теперь представьте, что вы просто участник форума, который не знаком с контекстом вашей проблемы, и попытайтесь понять то, что вы только что написали в вопросе. Получилось? Вот у меня нет. Пожалуйста, перепишите вопрос так, чтобы он стал понятен не только вам.

Comment: @Стас, изменил вопрос

Comment: Вас интересуют только действительные корни или комплексные тоже? Для данной системы уравнений нет действительных корней: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qw6F.png

Comment: @insolor, Это только для примера, я написал мне нужны все возможные числа. И вопрос был именно в том как сделать поиск, потому что перебором как у меня было раньше не нравилось

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я может в дебри залез и надо простенький алгоритм ...  Конкретно эти два уравнения не имеют общих решений. Вот доказательство используя Solver Z3. В условия добавляешь уравнения, переменные нужно объявить выше.

```
from z3 import *
solver = Solver()
x = BitVec('x', 64)
y = BitVec('y', 64)

# условия
constraints = [
    5 + x ^ 2 == y,
    y ^ 2 + x == 3
]

for i in constraints:
    solver.add(i) # добавляем условия в солвер
print(solver.check()) # проверяем есть ли решение sat - решение есть, unsat - решений не существует
while solver.check() == sat:
    print(solver.check())
    print(solver.model()[x], solver.model()[y])# если решение есть, выводим на экран x и y
    solver.add(x != solver.model()[x], y != solver.model()[y]) # добавляем условия, что новое решение на равно найденному
```

Алгоритм выдает unsat, решений нет.
Для примера

```
5 == y,
x == 3
```

Одно решение 3, 5

Comment: Но, это решение предлагает только один корень, а как получать несколько корней?

Comment: Этот алгоритм найдет все возможные решения, в пространстве 64битных векторов. Так как в последней строчке, добавляется условие, что решение не должно быть равно найденному и цикл запускается снова. И так пока новых решений не останется совсем.  например  для условий    (x + y == 7, x > 3, y > 0), программа выдаст  (6 1) (4 3) (5 2).

Answer (score 2):

Решение системы с помощью Sympy:

```
from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve

x, y = symbols("x y")

equations = [
    Eq(x**2 + 5, y),
    Eq(y**2 + x, 3)
]

results = solve(equations)
print(results)
# Вывод: [{x: 3 - (sqrt(4 + 34/(3*(209/16 + sqrt(235023)*I/144)**(1/3)) + 2*(209/16 + sqrt(235023)*I/144)**(1/3))/2 - sqrt(8 - 2*(209/16 + sqrt(235023)*I/144)**(1/3) + 2/sqrt(4 + 34/(3*(209/16 + sqrt(235023)*I/144)**(1/3)) + 2*(209/16 + sqrt(235023)*I/144)**(1/3)) - 34/(3*(209/16 + sqrt(235023)*I/144)**(1/3)))/2)**2, y: sqrt(4 + 34/(3*(209/16 + sqrt(235023)*I/144)**(1/3)) + 2*(209/16 + sqrt(235023)*I/144)**(1/3))/2 - sqrt(8 - 2*(209/16 + sqrt(235023)*I/144)**(1/3) + 2/sqrt(4 + 34/(3*(209/16 + sqrt(235023)*I/144)**(1/3)) + 2*(209/16 + sqrt(235023)*I/144)**(1/3)) - 34/(3*(209/16 + sqrt(235023)*I/144)**(1/3)))/2}, {x: 3 - (sqrt(8 - 2*(209/16 + sqrt(235023)*I/144)**(1/3) + 2/sqrt(4 + 34/(3*(209/16 + sqrt(235023)*I/144)**(1/3)) + 2*(209/16 + sqrt(235023)*I/144)**(1/3)) - 34/(3*(209/16 + sqrt(235023)*I/144)**(1/3)))/2 + sqrt(4 + 34/(3*(209/16 + sqrt(235023)*I/144)**(1/3)) + 2*(209/16 + sqrt(235023)*I/144)**(1/3))/2)**2, y: sqrt(8 - 2*(209/16 + sqrt(235023)*I/144)**(1/3) + 2/sqrt(4 + 34/(3*(209/16 + sqrt(235023)*I/144)**(1/3)) + 2*(209/16 + sqrt(235023)*I/144)**(1/3)) - 34/(3*(209/16 + sqrt(235023)*I/144)**(1/3)))/2 + sqrt(4 + 34/(3*(209/16 + sqrt(235023)*I/144)**(1/3)) + 2*(209/16 + sqrt(235023)*I/144)**(1/3))/2}]

# Вывод результатов в более читаемом виде
for result in results:
    print('x =', result[x])
    print(f'({result[x].evalf()})')
    print()
    print('y =', result[y])
    print(f'({result[y].evalf()})')
    print('\n')

# Вывод:
# x = 3 - (sqrt(4 + 34/(3*(209/16 + sqrt(235023)*I/144)**(1/3)) + 2*(209/16 + sqrt(235023)*I/144)**(1/3))/2 - sqrt(8 - 2*(209/16 + sqrt(235023)*I/144)**(1/3) + 2/sqrt(4 + 34/(3*(209/16 + sqrt(235023)*I/144)**(1/3)) + 2*(209/16 + sqrt(235023)*I/144)**(1/3)) - 34/(3*(209/16 + sqrt(235023)*I/144)**(1/3)))/2)**2
# (-0.136141938982763 - 1.78387663318005*I)

# y = sqrt(4 + 34/(3*(209/16 + sqrt(235023)*I/144)**(1/3)) + 2*(209/16 + sqrt(235023)*I/144)**(1/3))/2 - sqrt(8 - 2*(209/16 + sqrt(235023)*I/144)**(1/3) + 2/sqrt(4 + 34/(3*(209/16 + sqrt(235023)*I/144)**(1/3)) + 2*(209/16 + sqrt(235023)*I/144)**(1/3)) - 34/(3*(209/16 + sqrt(235023)*I/144)**(1/3)))/2
# (1.83631878514418 + 0.485720847494351*I)


# x = 3 - (sqrt(8 - 2*(209/16 + sqrt(235023)*I/144)**(1/3) + 2/sqrt(4 + 34/(3*(209/16 + sqrt(235023)*I/144)**(1/3)) + 2*(209/16 + sqrt(235023)*I/144)**(1/3)) - 34/(3*(209/16 + sqrt(235023)*I/144)**(1/3)))/2 + sqrt(4 + 34/(3*(209/16 + sqrt(235023)*I/144)**(1/3)) + 2*(209/16 + sqrt(235023)*I/144)**(1/3))/2)**2
# (-0.136141938982763 + 1.78387663318005*I)

# y = sqrt(8 - 2*(209/16 + sqrt(235023)*I/144)**(1/3) + 2/sqrt(4 + 34/(3*(209/16 + sqrt(235023)*I/144)**(1/3)) + 2*(209/16 + sqrt(235023)*I/144)**(1/3)) - 34/(3*(209/16 + sqrt(235023)*I/144)**(1/3)))/2 + sqrt(4 + 34/(3*(209/16 + sqrt(235023)*I/144)**(1/3)) + 2*(209/16 + sqrt(235023)*I/144)**(1/3))/2
# (1.83631878514418 - 0.485720847494351*I)
```

Видим, что система уравнений из вопроса имеет только комплексные решения. Правда, WolframAlfa дает для этой системы на два решения больше (кликабельно):

[image]

Если комплексные решения не нужны, проверяйте свойство `is_real` (например `result[x].evalf().is_real`), и решения где это свойство равно False не учитывайте:

```
# Убрал +5 в первом уравнении, чтобы появились действительные корни:
equations = [
    Eq(x**2, y),
    Eq(y**2 + x, 3)
]

...

for result in results:
    if result[x].evalf().is_real and result[y].evalf().is_real:
        print('x =', result[x])
        print(f'({result[x].evalf()})')
        print()
        print('y =', result[y])
        print(f'({result[y].evalf()})')
        print('\n')
```

Вывод:

```
x = 3 - (-sqrt(-2*(sqrt(257)/16 + 129/16)**(1/3) - 8/(sqrt(257)/16 + 129/16)**(1/3) + 2/sqrt(8/(sqrt(257)/16 + 129/16)**(1/3) + 4 + 2*(sqrt(257)/16 + 129/16)**(1/3)) + 8)/2 + sqrt(8/(sqrt(257)/16 + 129/16)**(1/3) + 4 + 2*(sqrt(257)/16 + 129/16)**(1/3))/2)**2
(1.16403514028977)

y = -sqrt(-2*(sqrt(257)/16 + 129/16)**(1/3) - 8/(sqrt(257)/16 + 129/16)**(1/3) + 2/sqrt(8/(sqrt(257)/16 + 129/16)**(1/3) + 4 + 2*(sqrt(257)/16 + 129/16)**(1/3)) + 8)/2 + sqrt(8/(sqrt(257)/16 + 129/16)**(1/3) + 4 + 2*(sqrt(257)/16 + 129/16)**(1/3))/2
(1.35497780782942)


x = 3 - (sqrt(-2*(sqrt(257)/16 + 129/16)**(1/3) - 8/(sqrt(257)/16 + 129/16)**(1/3) + 2/sqrt(8/(sqrt(257)/16 + 129/16)**(1/3) + 4 + 2*(sqrt(257)/16 + 129/16)**(1/3)) + 8)/2 + sqrt(8/(sqrt(257)/16 + 129/16)**(1/3) + 4 + 2*(sqrt(257)/16 + 129/16)**(1/3))/2)**2
(-1.45262687883384)

y = sqrt(-2*(sqrt(257)/16 + 129/16)**(1/3) - 8/(sqrt(257)/16 + 129/16)**(1/3) + 2/sqrt(8/(sqrt(257)/16 + 129/16)**(1/3) + 4 + 2*(sqrt(257)/16 + 129/16)**(1/3)) + 8)/2 + sqrt(8/(sqrt(257)/16 + 129/16)**(1/3) + 4 + 2*(sqrt(257)/16 + 129/16)**(1/3))/2
(2.11012484911056)
```